# In SDL Tridion 2013 - is there a cap of # groups you can belong to?

Tags: 2013-sp1

Have users that belongs to "many" groups.. it is actually 106.. (I know.. it is bad).. but when I now want to add a new group.. I get the popup to add, but the displayed "member of the following groups" are not updating.

So I wonder.. is there a limitation of how many groups you can belong to?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it's is not a problem of limitations, but a problem of timeout in the response if the number of groups or users is too long.
You can try changing the response time in the `SDL Tridion Management Console` in the `Timeout settins`.

There is a rendering timeout of 2 minutes (120000 msec) that can be put to "0" to "no timeout".

It's worth trying.